# Why am I getting so many hits searching for "git" in the apt cache?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I give the following command:

```
 apt-cache search git | wc -l
```

I get the answer 756. How can I list just the half-dozen or so apps associated with git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Search using anchors (`^...`)

You can just search for entries that start with the string "git" like so.

#### Example

```
$ apt-cache search ^git | head -10
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
git-core - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (obsolete)
git-doc - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (documentation)
git-man - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
gitk - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (revision tree visualizer)
easygit - git for mere mortals
gforge-plugin-scmgit - Git plugin for FusionForge (transitional package)
git-all - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (all subpackages)
git-annex - manage files with git, without checking their contents into git
git-arch - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (arch interoperability)
```

This is a subtle difference from just searching for the string "git" but the difference is that this search will find substrings that start with the string "git" whereas a bareword search for "git" will return entries such as "digital".

You can also restrict the output of `apt-cache search ^git` by piping the output into an additional `grep` like this:

#### Filter using grep

```
$ apt-cache search ^git | grep "^git" | head -10
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
git-core - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (obsolete)
git-doc - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (documentation)
git-man - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
gitk - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (revision tree visualizer)
git-all - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (all subpackages)
git-annex - manage files with git, without checking their contents into git
git-arch - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (arch interoperability)
git-buildpackage - Suite to help with Debian packages in Git repositories
git-cola - highly caffeinated git GUI
```

Which will only show packages whose names start with the string "git".

#### Use the switch `--names-only`

This will only search the package names for matches that start with the string "git".

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only ^git | head -10
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
git-core - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (obsolete)
git-doc - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (documentation)
git-man - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
gitk - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (revision tree visualizer)
git-all - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (all subpackages)
git-annex - manage files with git, without checking their contents into git
git-arch - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (arch interoperability)
git-buildpackage - Suite to help with Debian packages in Git repositories
git-cola - highly caffeinated git GUI
```

Comment: Suggest mentioning using `\b` to search for whole words (`apt-cache search '\bgit\b'`. Or `apt-cache search '\<git\>'` if `\b` hasn't always worked.)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because this:

```
apt-cache show libqt5sensors5 | grep -i git
Version: 5.0~git20130507-0ubuntu1~raring1~test1
 WARNING: This module is not an official part of Qt 5, but instead a git
Version: 5.0~git20130115-0ubuntu1
Filename: pool/universe/q/qtsensors-opensource-src/libqt5sensors5_5.0~git20130115-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Some packages are "git" related, some others just have "git" somewhere in the description, since `apt-cache search` do not only search in the packages name but in the short/long description.

> How can I list just the half-dozen or so apps associated with git?

```
apt-cache search git | grep -i git
```

That will show you only the packages that have "git" in the short description or the package name.

Comment: The command "apt-cache search git | grep -i git | wc -l" gives the answer 201.

Comment: ?? is less then before no? and they are all git related. There are also "di**git**al" which you can exclude if you add `| grep -vi digital`. In my system the result is 118 and it can be narrowed down even more.

Comment: the solution is  apt-cache search git | grep ^git

Comment: That will ignore things like `python-setuptools-git - plugin for setuptools that enables git integration`

Comment: `grep '\bgit\b'` would be a good solution to filter out digital, etc.